# Sum DataGridView c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, datagridview

I would like to show into a `label` the resul of the **sum** of all cells of one column. I tried one code that I saw in the net but the code doesnt work.

Here's the code:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv_Carrinho.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(t => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Cells["Valor"].Value?.ToString())))
            {
                lbl_Subtotal.Text += (Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Valor"].Value)).ToString();
            }
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: Create a variable that will contain the value, such as `var totalAmount = 0.0D;` and then inside of your `foreach` statement do `totalAmount += Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Valor"].Value));` then `OUTSIDE` of your `foreach` loop, set the `lbl_Subtotal.Text` to the `totalAmount.ToString()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to calculate sum first, then assign it to  `lbl_Subtotal.Text`, something like

```
var sum = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv_Carrinho.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(t => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Cells["Valor"].Value?.ToString())))
    sum += (Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Valor"].Value));

//Now assign it to label
 lbl_Subtotal.Text = sum.ToString();
```

---

Lets try some linq operations,

```
var sum = dgv_Carrinho.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
     .Select(double.TryParse(row.Cells["Valor"].Value?.ToString(), out double value) ? value : 0)
     .Sum();
//Now assign it to label
lbl_Subtotal.Text = sum.ToString();
```

Comment: I tried the first option and it still doesn't working...

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: It were already fixed, thanks anyway

Comment: @sharp.programer, If my answer helped you to solve your query then don't forget to accept it by ✔

Comment: It's not does the sum `qtd = double.Parse(cmb_Quantidade.Text);
                    valor = double.Parse(lbl_MostraValor.Text);
                    double subtotal = (qtd * valor);
                        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv_Carrinho.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>())
                        {
                            subtotal += Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Valor"].Value);
                        }
                            lbl_Subtotal.Text = subtotal.ToString();
                    dgv_Carrinho.Rows.Add(txt_Produto.Text, subtotal, cmb_Quantidade.Text, txt_Hora.Text);`

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv_Carrinho.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(t => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Cells["Valor"].Value?.ToString())))
{
     count += (Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Valor"].Value)).ToString();
}
lbl_Subtotal.Text = count.ToSring();
```

Answer (score 0):

u can add extension function for DataGridView

```
public double getSumCell(this DataGridView GridView, string ColName)
{
    double sumValue = (from d in GridView.Rows
                       select d).Sum(DataGridViewRow x => Convert.ToDouble(x.Cells(ColName).Value));

    return sumValue;
}
```

usage:

```
lbl_Subtotal.Text = dgv_Carrinho.getSumCell("COLUMN_NAME");
```